# Cannot get sample google-api-python-client/samples/urlshortener/ to work

Tags: python, google-oauth, google-url-shortener

I am trying to write a python script that will get the number click on my goo.gl shorteded URL.  I figured I could try and get this sample to work first:

https://github.com/google/google-api-python-client/tree/master/samples/urlshortener

I have my `client_secrets.json` filled out like so (actually client_id and client_secret are obfuscated) here:

```
{
  "other": {
    "client_id": "[['mYcLIent_1dapps.googleusercontent.com']]",
    "client_secret": "[['mYCLient_53cr3t']]",
    "redirect_uris": [],
    "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
    "token_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token"
  }
}
```

But when I execute the script I get this:

```
$ ./urlshortener.py --logging_level=DEBUG
WARNING: Please configure OAuth 2.0

To make this sample run you will need to populate the client_secrets.json file
found at:

   ./client_secrets.json

with information from the APIs Console <https://code.google.com/apis/console>.
```

Comment: nope :(          7 more characters to go

Comment: Couldn't solve the problem with the sample, but confirmed that the lib works. If you create the Service object and call `insert` as showed in the sample, it works.

Comment: You aren't using the brackets in the `client_id` and `client_secret`, are you?

Comment: Also, try changing `"other"` to `"web"`